# Execute PostAsync with empty response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

For my UPW App with MS Store integration, my ASP.NET application does some calls to the Microsoft Store collection API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/monetize/report-consumable-products-as-fulfilled

This API method has no return at all:

"***Response***:
No content will be returned if the consumption was executed successfully."

Which causes my following code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
String content = "...";
var res = httpClient.PostAsync("https://collections.mp.microsoft.com/v6.0/collections/consume", content).Result;
```

To throw an exception. Unfortunately I only have it in german, but it tells that from the connection no data could be read, and that the remote host has closed the connection.

I think this is basically a "feature" and not a bug, because there **really is no content** to return. But I dont know how to get rid of the exception.

Exception:
*System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Fehler beim Senden der Anforderung. ---> System.Net.WebException: Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unbekannter Fehler beim Empfangen.. ---> System.IO.IOException: Von der Übertragungsverbindung können keine Daten gelesen werden: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
   bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   bei System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 ...*

Comment: As an aside, you should not use the Result property of the returned Task but await the PostAsync method.

Answer (score 1):

That is a network error.

The documentation ([this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/report-consumable-products-as-fulfilled) is the English version) does say:

> No content will be returned if the consumption was executed successfully.

However, it also gives an [example of a response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/report-consumable-products-as-fulfilled#response-example):

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Length: 0
MS-CorrelationId: 386f733d-bc66-4bf9-9b6f-a1ad417f97f0
MS-RequestId: e488cd0a-9fb6-4c2c-bb77-e5100d3c15b1
MS-CV: 5.1
MS-ServerId: 030011326
Date: Tue, 22 Sep 2015 20:40:55 GMT
```

So it does respond, but with [HTTP 204](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204).

If you are not getting that response, then you have a network problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It may respond 204, but the mentioned line of code throws the exception. And it was defnitelely not a network error. I know this because: After the exception was thrown and I requested again, the item was really purchased. That means, the call went trough and was executed. But the exception was thrown anyway.

Comment: So yes, the request was processed, but the error is saying that the network connection was closed before you could get the response. That should not happen. There should be no exception if everything is working properly.